whenever i pressing the + button the increment opereator is changing the value in the localstorage but after refreshing value is gone from the UI
as the Title suggests when i am refreshing the Qty changes back to 1 no matter how much you increment before but the value of count is changing in the localstorage
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Cart() {
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const location = useLocation();

  // console.log(location?.state?.data);
  useEffect(() => {
    const userDataString = localStorage.getItem("item");
    if (userDataString) {
      const userData = JSON.parse(userDataString);
      console.log("userData:", userData);
      const groupedItems = userData.reduce((acc, item) => {
        console.log("item:", item);
        const existingItem = acc.find((group) => group?.id === item?.id);
        if (existingItem) {
          existingItem.count++;
        } else {
          acc.push({ ...item, count: 1 });
        }
        return acc;
      }, []);
      console.log("groupedItems:", groupedItems);
      setDetail(groupedItems);
    }
  }, []);

    </>
  );
}

